# Find records which date range collides with another date range

Tags: postgresql, date, overlap, date-range

Let's bet that user wants to find a records which date range collides with given range: <2018-01-01; 2018-02-28>

For example, we have a given dataset

```
|--- FROM --- | --- TO --- | ------ COLLIDES ------ |
| 2018-01-01  | 2018-01-05 | YES (with all 5 days)  |
| 2018-01-01  | 2018-01-01 | YES (with 1 day)       |
| 2017-12-20  | 2019-10-19 | YES (with all 5 days)  |
| 2017-12-25  | 2017-12-31 | NO                     |
| 2018-03-01  | 2018-03-20 | NO                     |
```

Is there efficient way to filter through dataset for given date range collision?

Answer (score 0):

Done with

```
select date_from, date_to, (date_from, date_to) 
OVERLAPS(DATE '2018-01-01' - interval '1 day', DATE '2018-02-28' + interval '1 day') 
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

[just checking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html):

```
t=# with c(f,t) as (values('2018-01-01'::date,'2018-01-05'::date))
select daterange(f,t,'()') && '(2018-01-01, 2018-02-28)'::daterange from c;
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

[and the intersection value:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

```
t=# with c(f,t) as (values('2018-01-01'::date,'2018-01-05'::date))
select daterange(f,t,'()') * '(2018-01-01, 2018-02-28)'::daterange from c;
        ?column?
-------------------------
 [2018-01-02,2018-01-05)
(1 row)
```